# Azure Pipeline run Qt application

Tags: qt, azure-devops, qt5

Simpe Qt App 'untitled.exe':

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>

void parseCmd(const QCoreApplication &app)
{
   QCommandLineParser parser;
   parser.addHelpOption();
   parser.addVersionOption();
   parser.process(app);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion("1.0");

   parseCmd(a);

   return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
2020-12-15T19:06:08.1133300Z ##[section]Starting: Test code...
2020-12-15T19:06:08.1434531Z ==============================================================================
2020-12-15T19:06:08.1434873Z Task         : Command line
2020-12-15T19:06:08.1435197Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2020-12-15T19:06:08.1435509Z Version      : 2.178.0
2020-12-15T19:06:08.1436101Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-12-15T19:06:08.1436429Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2020-12-15T19:06:08.1436801Z ==============================================================================
2020-12-15T19:06:09.5889046Z Generating script.
2020-12-15T19:06:09.6545863Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7002067Z ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\cc51db57-c085-4347-873f-ed28f0e7af53.cmd""
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7240225Z         1 file(s) copied.
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7388204Z  Volume in drive D is Temp
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7389142Z  Volume Serial Number is 405E-826C
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7389470Z 
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7389984Z  Directory of D:\a\1\s\Release_WIN_x64
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7390270Z 
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7390552Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM    <DIR>          .
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7392444Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7393989Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM    <DIR>          bearer
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7394372Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM    <DIR>          iconengines
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7394795Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM    <DIR>          imageformats
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7395287Z 12/08/2020  02:33 PM         3,409,920 libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7395702Z 12/08/2020  02:33 PM           682,496 libssl-1_1-x64.dll
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7399561Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM            47,104 MainApp-1.0.0.exe
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7400169Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM           594,944 MaintenanceTool-1.0.0.exe
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7400757Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM    <DIR>          platforms
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7401416Z 05/11/2020  08:46 AM         5,998,712 Qt5Core.dll
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7401954Z 05/11/2020  08:47 AM         7,085,176 Qt5Gui.dll
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7404188Z 05/11/2020  08:47 AM         1,349,240 Qt5Network.dll
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7404743Z 05/11/2020  03:05 PM           329,848 Qt5Svg.dll
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7405277Z 05/11/2020  08:47 AM         5,516,920 Qt5Widgets.dll
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7405719Z 12/15/2020  07:06 PM    <DIR>          styles
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7406168Z 12/15/2020  07:05 PM            10,240 untitled.exe
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7406588Z               10 File(s)     25,024,600 bytes
2020-12-15T19:06:09.7407293Z                7 Dir(s)  11,920,207,872 bytes free
2020-12-15T19:06:09.8738006Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-1073741701'.
2020-12-15T19:06:09.9214918Z ##[section]Finishing: Test code...
```

And i try to run that in azure pipeline but is failed to run with -v params (that should show version number).

As all dlls are in place, application is crashing, as also others apps are similar like in example 'MainApp' and 'MaintenanceTool' - using same 'core' stuff.

When i run 'MainApp' or 'MaintenanceTool' - azure wait forever, and only way to stop pipeline is cancel.

Weird thing is that i'm able to compile, but not run :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem, that is for Azure pipelines.

As Qt class QCommandLineParser is using 'qApp' that can be Core, or GUI app (in my case was QApplication) - when we run app with -v (default option for QCommandLineParser) was/is show MessageBox (just show GUI pop-up) with version.

So when we use that in 'command line pipe line' - there no way that we can click Ok on taht dialog.

Based on code from [Can I use QCommandLineParser to determine GUI mode or CLI mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649458/can-i-use-qcommandlineparser-to-determine-gui-mode-or-cli-mode)
 i made some example that is just print version - as this was requirement for me :)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <iostream> // For std::
#include <QtCore>

// Use any other flags from cmd ...
struct Options {
   bool version = false;
};

Options parseCmd()
{
   QCommandLineParser parser;

   // parser.addVersionOption(); DO NOT USE THIS!

   QCommandLineOption showVer("ver", "Show program version.");
   parser.addOption(showVer);

   // Procs args
   parser.process(*qApp);

   // Save data
   Options opts = {};
   opts.version = parser.isSet(showVer);

   return opts;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::cout << "Create core app" << std::endl;
   QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion("1.0");

   // Create base core app
   QScopedPointer<QCoreApplication> app(new QCoreApplication(argc, argv));

   // Parse cmd parameters
   std::cout << "Parse cmd params" << std::endl;
   Options opt = parseCmd();

   // If only display version
   if(opt.version)
   {
      std::cout << "Display version" << std::endl;
      std::cout << qApp->applicationVersion().toStdString() << std::endl;
   } else
   {
      std::cout << "Run in gui mode" << std::endl;
      // Reset app to GUI mode
      app.reset();
      app.reset(new QApplication(argc, argv));
   }

   //
   if(qobject_cast<QApplication*>(qApp))
   {
      std::cout << "Show QMessageBox" << std::endl;
      // Create any GUI stuff here
      QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Hello", "Hello, World!");
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Send quit message" << std::endl;
      // As we run QCoreApplication only for parsing cmd params ...
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
   }

   //
   return app->exec();
}
```

Also we need and extra line into project file: '''CONFIG   += console'''

```
QT       += core gui widgets
CONFIG   += console
TEMPLATE =  app
SOURCES  += main.cpp
```

And that how we can 'show' version in command line ;)

Comment: One more note: When we run application under windows cmd with -v (show version that is default with 'addVersionOption' of parser), its working correctly.

Only way to show gui/windowed mode of version is run under QtCreator - so we run application with gui libs? Not sure how that is work under azure pipelines, but above code won't display any gui stuff :)

Comment: That's great you found the issue. You can accept your own solution. Azure pipeline cannot display gui stuff during execution.